# How do I filter data with two parameter from two different Django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create a JSON object which will

1. Search the particular Projects from the model "EmpProject" by a specific emp_id
2. Search whose project status is "Pending"  from the model "Project" with the help of (1.) Search result

I am using JSON Parser (no models or generic view)

## Models

Below are my models I have not use many to many field  instead I created a Intermediate Table if the solution is also possible by using manytomanyfield than also suggest

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employeeid = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dept_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name


class Project(models.Model):
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,)
    project_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectname

class EmpProject(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['emp_id','project_id']]
        ordering = ('project_id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_id
```

## Serializer

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dept_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Department.objects.all(), slug_field='dept_name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'id',
            'employeeid',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone_no',
            'date_of_birth',
            'email',
            'password',
            'designation',
            'dept_id',
        ]


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'id',
            'projectname',
            'project_status',
            'description',
            'start_date',
            'due_date'  ,
        ]


class EmpProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emp_id=serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(),slug_field='employeeid')
    project_id=serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Project.objects.all(),slug_field='projectname')
    class Meta:
        model = EmpProject
        fields = [
            'emp_id',
            'project_id',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Project.objects.filter(id__in=EmpProject.objects.filter(id__in=emp_id).values("project_id"), project_status="Pending")
```

Few points worth mentioning:

1. It's good idea to use a intermediate table when we want to have extra data related to association. But for that kindly have a look at `through` attribute supported in `ManyToManyField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through
2. `project_status` is `CharField`, I think you should consider `ChoiceField`, charfield may introduce lots of dirty data in database.

Comment: It's not working as I am using Model Serailizer, your code require two serialzier

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: This is my view which accept the emp_id as a parameter
How should I use your code here ?
************************
@csrf_exempt
def project_list_name(request, empid):
    projects = Project.objects.filter(id__in=EmpProject.objects.filter(id__in=empid).values("project_id"), project_status="Pending")
        
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        projects_serializer = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(projects_serializer.data, safe=False)
**********

Comment: What error are you getting with this ? I think you'll need to pass projects as instances attribute to the serializer.

Comment: `projects_serializer = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)`
 I passed the projects instance to the serializer